# React - Link to doesn't always work as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am building a Pinterest clone that uses React on the front-end.

The home page is `/pins`, which is just an index of all the pins. In the Pin Index Item component, when a user clicks on the pin, I am using Link to go to the correct path.

Here is the Link to in the PinIndexItem.jsx

```
<Link to={`users/${pin.author_id}/boards/${pin.board_id}/pins/${pin.id}`}>
```

Here is the Route in my App.jsx

```
<Switch>
 <ProtectedRoute exact path='/users/:userId/boards/:boardId/pins/:pinId' component={PinShowContainer} />
</Switch>
```

When I go from the pins route, which is

```
#/pins/
```

It works just fine

However, I am on a user's pin board, which is

```
users/${pin.author_id}/boards/${pin.board_id}/
```

instead of going to

```
users/${pin.author_id}/boards/${pin.board_id}/pins/${pin.id}
```

, it adds onto the path:

`users/${pin.author_id}/boards/`users/${pin.author_id}/boards/${pin.board_id}/pins/${pin.id}`

I am confused why it works differently in the second case. Thank you.

Should I just use `history.push` in both cases?

Comment: show your link code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a link element, if you omit the initial `/` on the `href` attribute (the target URL for the link), the `href` attribute value will be appended to the current URL. This is a link relative to the current page (`href` value will be appended to the current page full URL).

For example if the current page URL is `/here` and you set up a link with `href="there"`, then clicking on that link will get you to `/here/there`.

If you want to set up a link to an absolute path, you need to add an initial `/` on the `href` attribute. From my previous example, if the current page URL is `/here` and you set up a link with `href="/there"`, then clicking on that link will get you to `/there`.

You should be able to solve your problem by switching to absolute paths, or use different relative paths.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a for a complete doc.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe it was that simple! It worked!

Comment: Happy to help !